# strongloop loopback app via strong-pm *app* log to file?

Tags: logging, strongloop, loopback

From the [docs](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/Logging):

> you can dump the last 1 MByte of log file content to the console with
>   this command:
>
> ```
> slc ctl log-dump my-app --follow
> ```

And the disheartening followup,

> "The slc ctl log-dump command actually *consumes* the log messages, so if more than one person calls it for one application, only one of them will see the logs."

What is the reasoning for this? And where does it consume them from? **How would I redirect to a file?**

I am running strong-pm as an upstart service and I can tail its log at `/var/log/upstart/strong-pm.log`. But this is for strong-pm stuff, and does not have any logging specific to my app.

The [section on "Logging in production"](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/Logging) (also on [setting up a prod host](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/Setting+up+a+production+host#Settingupaproductionhost-Logging)) says that upstart is responsible for logging, but that's only for strong-pm, not my app. Is this section just not complete? Is there another section of the docs I should read?

Comment: There was a regression in functionality when multiple app support was added. The app logs are supposed to be going to the strong-pm log file and the log-dump command is just supposed to be a convenience to get a quick view of the app-specific log without ssh'ing in and digging through the log file directly.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality has been improved since this was originally posted.

What we do now is simply send `/var/log/strong-pm.log` contents via rsyslog and a couple other services to capture logs and errors off-site. This log now contains all the errors and `console.log()` output contained in the app.